# Why is my simple Angular ui.router not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the simplest ui.router example which doesn't seem to work.

See below:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {   

    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); When I uncomment this, it loads /home without a problem but why is it going to the "otherwise" condition?

    $stateProvider       
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    })
});
```

My index file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angularApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="mainApp">

<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have been going on and on into this but I think I now have tunnel vision. Someone please help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the html and js/ts file where you defined the angular component ui-view (not sure if that's the one)

Comment: This is angularjs not angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any issue except you having the same controller for both, can you check the example below

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider.state('top', {
      url: "",
      templateUrl: "header.html",
      controller: 'topCtrl'
    })
    .state('top.side', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: "side.html",
      controller: 'filterCtrl'
    })
    .state('top.side.list', {
      url: "/items?query",
      templateUrl: "items.html",
      controller: 'listCtrl'
    })
    .state('top.side.item', {
      url: "/:id",
      templateUrl: "item.html",
      controller: 'itemCtrl'
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fz75ts5fto1HXjLIIkue)

Comment: This works like a charm! I updated the versions thought as it was using a very old one but it worked without any further changes. Thanks a lot mate!